# Spanning table cells in html

Tags: html, css

I am doing some basic HTML - make a table and combine two cells, one below the other. **I am trying to learn rowspan. So, I cannot remove the rowspan.**

I tried the stuff in my book, with minor modifications. I get the result below. I want the second row (potato) to appear below the the first one. How do I do this ?

[image]

HTML code -

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rowspan.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <th>SaleItem</th><th>MoneyEarned</th>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">Apple & Mango</td><td>35</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Potato</td><td>15</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS code -

```
td[rowspan|="2"] {background: orange;}
```

Book example -

[image]

**EDIT -**

After adding `<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>` after the first row, I get the output below. The orange cell is just one cell thick and not two, like my book. Why ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rowspan` was breaking the table layout removing it will fix the layout

```css
td.orange {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<table border=0>
  <th>SaleItem</th>
  <th>MoneyEarned</th>
  <tr>
    <td class="orange">Apple & Mango</td>
    <td>35</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Potato</td>
    <td>15</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

so you need to add extra row below to fix the `rowspan`

```css
td.orange {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <th>SaleItem</th>
  <th>MoneyEarned</th>
  <tr>
    <td class="orange" rowspan="2">Apple & Mango</td>
    <td>35</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Potato</td>
    <td>15</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```css
td{
padding:2px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>row 1</td>

    <td rowspan="2">col merge</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="3">all col merge</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row 2</td>
    <td rowspan="2">col merge</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row 3</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I am trying to learn rowspan. So, I cannot remove that. Let me add it to my question.

Comment: so you need to add extra row below to fix the `rowspan` @Steam

Comment: Yes, I tried that before `<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>` and it looks like one orange row instead of two orange rows. I was hoping to make it like the book (Image added)

Answer (score 0):

As your rows are spanning 2 in first rows case. You need to enter a blank row to account for it:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rowspan.css">
</head>


<body> 

    <table>
        <th>SaleItem</th><th>MoneyEarned</th>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Apple & Mango</td><td>35</td>
        </tr>
    <tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Potato</td><td>15</td>  
        </tr>
    </table>

    </body>

</html>
```

More relevant use of rowspan:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rowspan.css">
</head>


<body> 

    <table>
        <th>SaleItem</th><th>Day</th><th>MoneyEarned</th>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Apple & Mango</td><td>Day1</td><td>35</td>
        </tr>
    <tr><td>Day2</td><td>25</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Potato</td><td>Only one day</td><td>15</td> 
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
```

Comment: We can feel a better use of rowspan incase we are having rate of apple on mango in two different cities. So the second row will have a good reason to be merged with top. (edited code above to include the code)

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like, the highest priority is given to the first row, then the second row and so on. First you, specify the rowspans for the **td**'s in first row, then, if the second row has any columns which are free, then add that many **td**'s. And so, on. You can find the example below.

http://jsbin.com/yovahe/1/edit?html,output